# Documented typeclass instances not imported in Haskell

Tags: haskell, module, typeclass

I'm trying to use the UTCTime instance CalendarTimeConvertible found in the [time-recurrence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-recurrence-0.9.3/docs/Data-Time-CalendarTime.html) library. It's listed in the documentation, but when I import the library into ghci and evaluate `i: CalendarTimeConvertible`, the instance doesn't appear.

```
class CalendarTimeConvertible t where
  toCalendarTime :: t -> CalendarTime
  fromCalendarTime :: CalendarTime -> Maybe t
    -- Defined in ‘time-recurrence-0.9.3:Data.Time.CalendarTime.CalendarTime’
instance CalendarTimeConvertible CalendarTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-recurrence-0.9.3:Data.Time.CalendarTime.CalendarTime’
```

Nor does it show up in the output to `i: UTCTime`.

```
data UTCTime = UTCTime {utctDay :: Day, utctDayTime :: DiffTime}
    -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Eq UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Ord UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Read UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Format.Parse’
instance Show UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.LocalTime.Internal.ZonedTime’
instance ParseTime UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Format.Parse.Instances’
instance FormatTime UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Format.Format.Instances’
```

I can't figure it out. Is there an import step I'm missing? I searched for ways to explicitly import typeclass instances but came up empty.

**Edit:**
Here is my session:

```
λ> import Data.Time.Clock
λ> :i UTCTime
data UTCTime
  = UTCTime {utctDay :: time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Calendar.Days.Day,
             utctDayTime :: DiffTime}
    -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Eq UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Ord UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Read UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Format.Parse’
instance Show UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.LocalTime.Internal.ZonedTime’
λ> import Data.Time.CalendarTime
λ> :i CalendarTimeConvertible
class CalendarTimeConvertible t where
  toCalendarTime :: t -> CalendarTime
  fromCalendarTime :: CalendarTime -> Maybe t
    -- Defined in ‘time-recurrence-0.9.3:Data.Time.CalendarTime.CalendarTime’
instance CalendarTimeConvertible CalendarTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-recurrence-0.9.3:Data.Time.CalendarTime.CalendarTime’
λ> :i UTCTime
data UTCTime
  = UTCTime {utctDay :: time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Calendar.Days.Day,
             utctDayTime :: DiffTime}
    -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Eq UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Ord UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime’
instance Read UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.Format.Parse’
instance Show UTCTime
  -- Defined in ‘time-1.9.1:Data.Time.LocalTime.Internal.ZonedTime’
λ>
```

Comment: ghci doesnt show instances if the type isn't in scope. Can you include the full ghci session including all imports and the order in which you're checking things?

Comment: Updated with session information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it means that you have two different versions of the same type in scope. E.g. you have `UTCTime` from `time-1.9.1`, but `time-recurrence` defines the instance for `UTCTime` from `time-1.5.0.1`.

To check the theory, try to run `ghc-pkg list time`. If I'm right, it will list two different versions installed.

Also, note that `time-recurrence` doesn't support `time-1.9.1`. It has the following constraints on `time`:

```
time >= 1.4 && < 1.6
```

It confirms my theory.

You can fix it using `ghci -hide-package time-1.5.0.1`

Answer (score 4):

`time-recurrence` depends on `time < 1.6`, but your session is using `time-1.9.1`. This means that the `time` package that was imported is not the same  as the `time` that `time-recurrence` is using, so the `UTCTime` type that has an instance is not in scope.

You need to somehow either hide the newer `time` or fix `time-recurrence` to build with it.